# Qt project, no rule to make target needed by

Tags: qt, makefile

I have a problem with my Makefile. I downloaded opensource Qt project. Hence, when I try to compile it I got a message:

```
error: No rule to make target needed by stop.
```

In my `.pro` file I have relative paths to `*.cpp` files. So when I replace relative paths to absolute it works, another case it got me with the error above.
System is Linux.

---

What should I do to do this work with the relative paths?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use QtCreator, opening the project and then adding one of the misplaced sources (let say the first you see in .pro).

The IDE should place it with the *correct* relative path, as appropriate per your folder choice. After that cut'n'paste the path prefix all over the remaining places.

Anyway, path prefixes should be relative to the directory where you find the .pro. An example from an opensource project I'm using (QZXIng, a Qt port of ZXing):

```
SOURCES += CameraImageWrapper.cpp \
    QZXing.cpp \
    imagehandler.cpp \
    zxing/ResultPointCallback.cpp \
    zxing/ResultPoint.cpp \
    zxing/Result.cpp \
    ...
```

so you could try to move the .pro file where appropriate instead of changing relative paths...

Comment: I found answer, I had to turn off option "Shadow" in Build Settings of Qt Creator. Thks anyway!

Comment: @Robert Could you please tell me where to find that option. I am facing the same problem and I cannot find this option in `Tools/Options`

Comment: @GuidoG, you'll find the `Shadow Build` checkbox in the `Projects` tab (left pannel, look for a wrench), then in the `General` category in the Build Settings.

Answer (score 5):

One reason for this issue is because you have removed a file which you no longer need but forgot remove from res.qrc

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and it was because I had the wrong Kit selected under Projects>Build & Run

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error. My pro file was

```
HEADERS       = \
                charectertranformer.h \
                filereader.h \
                svgview.h \
                threadfilereader.h \
                serverworker.h \
                renderserver.h
SOURCES       = \
                charectertranformer.cpp \
                filereader.cpp \
                main.cpp \
                svgview.cpp \
                threadfilereader.cpp \
                serverworker.cpp \
                renderserver.cpp \
QT += concurrent
QT += opengl
QT += network
QT += svg
CONFIG -= console
#CONFIG += warn_off exceptions_off
#qmake -svgviewer.pro
```

deleting backslash after renderserver.cpp helps me

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing two file ".qmake.stash" and ".qmake.cache" file

```
Open terminal: 
ls -a 
rm -rf .qmake.stash 
rm -rf .qmake.cache
```